# service principal account on-prem AD Connect sync

Tags: azure, azure-active-directory, service-principal

creating an SPN in Azure (single AD tenant) works very well, however, due some compliance reasons, organization says we have to creaty every user (including service ones) using on-prem AD, then sync via AD connect to Azure AD tenant.
That works very well for all the users (UPN), but can we sync those kind of objectes (SPN) on-prem -> Azure. I know it sounds a bit weird to create a SPN intended for Azure on on-prem AD, wait some time and do the work, but at the end it's all about syncing the objects.
Any help would be appreciated.
Thanks,
Stan

Answer (score -1):

I do not believe it is possible. AAD SP is an AAD-only entity. Has no meaning in AD.